# Unit Test Angular Pagination

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, pagination, jasmine, mocha.js

I use this in my header to GET all data, i parse (toJson) header in my controller:

```
X-Pagination:{"current_page":1,"per_page":10,"total_pages":16,"sub_count":10,"total_count":159}

var parsingHeader = angular.fromJson(vms.headers('X-Pagination'));
          _this.current_page = parsingHeader.current_page;
          _this.per_page = parsingHeader.per_page;
          _this.total_pages = parsingHeader.total_pages;
          _this.total_count = parsingHeader.total_count;
```

I want to test this :

```
$httpBackend
      .whenGET('http://localhost:3000/vms.json?page=1')
      .respond(function(method, url, data, headers){
        ...
      });
```

I have some error : 
'null' is not an object (evaluating 'parsingHeader.current_page'),...
What is the best process for Test this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the header `X-Pagination:{"current_page":1,"per_page":10,"total_pages":16,"sub_count":10,"total_count":159}` to your whenGET. I see no headers passed thats why the `parsingHeader` variable is null

Do something like this:

```
$httpBackend
      .whenGET('http://localhost:3000/vms.json?page=1', ['X-Pagination':{"current_page":1,"per_page":10,"total_pages":16,"sub_count":10,"total_count":159}] )
      .respond(function(method, url, data, headers){
        ...
      });
```

Comment: Can you show me an example please ? In my respond or in URL ?

Comment: read the angular docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend The whenGet supports headers... see `whenGET(url, [headers], [keys]);`

Comment: `$httpBackend.whenGET('http://localhost:3000/vms.json?page=1', [{'X-Pagination' : {'current_page': 1 ,"per_page":'10',"total_pages":'16',"sub_count":'10',"total_count":'159'}}] ).respond(function(method, url, data, headers){console.log(data);});`
It return :  No more request expected

Comment: I didnt check the syntax of header parameter.. pls do some more research there may be a typo. No more request can happen either your request is bad (maybe typo), or you didnt list all requests you going to make.